# Fit image inside a responsive div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap so I don't exactly know how it works !
What I want to do is to make the 3 images shown in the screen shot of same size.
Their resolutions are different .
 
This is the html for each image

```html
 <div class="col-sm-2 ">

    <div> <img src="img/test.jpg"> </div>

    <div > <h3>Text Here</h3> </div>
    
   </div>
```

This is the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add `class="img-responsive"` to your img and for the same size display you can add some custome class such as my_img and set the size there:

```
my_img{
height: 200px
width: 150px
}
```

or set a default height to the parent. Than you can do width: 100%; height: 100%

So what you know have is a column. That sets the width. than you have a div which has no class yet. You can add style to that div or to the img directly.

Comment: If I specify the dimensions myself will the div still.be responsive ? Because now if I resize the browser to a mobile screen size the images gets stacks vertically and their heights won't 'look' like it's different but when I open in a desktop it becomes the different dimensions become noticeable ! And the width is the same ! Only the height doesn't match ! Ty in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The column is responsive by default so just give the `img` a `width: 100%;` (it will scale to parent element) and that div will scale to its parent element as well which is `col-sm-2`.

Comment: I have set the image width to 100% and the width is not a problem , but the height of these images are not matching ! I tried height = 100% but it doesn't change ! Thanks !

Comment: If I understand correctly (you should add you're code with the stack snippet) you can, instead of adding `width: 100%;` you could do `height: 100%;` to the images use `overflow-x: hidden;` this way (if your images are not the same size) all images will be the same height and if one has a larger width than the other the parent element will hide the overflow on the x axis.